# Is there any function to check an incomplete HTML sources code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my web page, part of the html source code is provided by other party, I found that sometime the return sources code is incomplete, e.g.:

```
<table>
    <tr valign='top'>
        <td width=95>
            <img src='test.jpg'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h2><a style='font-size: 13px' href='tset.html'>test</a></h2>
            <h1><a href='test.html'>test</a></li>
```

I want to ask if there any function to check if the HTML sources code is incomplete?

I have a idea to use `substr()` to check first and last HTML tag, but dunno if it is work.

Thanks

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: When you say "function," do you mean something you can call from JavaScript as part of whatever process you're doing that accepts the HTML from the third party?

Comment: Checking for the first tag and the last tag (and no text around!) is sometimes sufficient, and seems like a good heuristic.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, something like a JavaScript function to check the HTML sources code inside my page, if the code is complete, then render it.

Comment: @JanDvorak In the case of OP, it might be hard if there isn't an enclosing element.

Comment: I doubt there is a simple solution here. The best would probably be to build an heuristic which would be very dependent on what you may expect from the particular service you're connecting to.

Comment: @dystroy it seems as if only the table should be the content. Then checking if the source is `^<(\w+)[^>]*>.*</\1>$` looks like a good heuristic, and if there are no nested tables, the false positive rate is exactly zero.

Comment: You *could* pass the 3rd party html code into a jQuery object and then render it that way? I can't guarantee it will work though and might lead to unexpected results. var maybeFixed = $("<table><h1>malformed html</h2>"); I should add that it fixes your sample code perfectly. Mine was more of a worst case sample.

Comment: @JanDvorak So you mean using regex to check the HTML code?

Comment: @CharlesYeung The regex will only verify the starting and the ending tag are the same and there's no text around. It won't verify the tags inside are matched. It still seems to me the false negative rate is very low.

Comment: @JanDvorak Could you please post your regex suggestion in details as the answer? Thanks

Comment: If there's only a table expected as a result, then just checking the HTML ends with `</table>` would do the same.

Comment: @dystroy Is it something like: `thirdPartySources.substr(-10).indexOf('</table>') > -1`?

Comment: @CharlesYeung The regex suggested by Jan would do the same but would be (slightly) more complete. If you don't need a real completion test and if this simple heuristic is compatible with what you expect from the server, then it's probably the best answer you'll get (Jan should thus make a proper answer from it in my opinion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking that the response starts and ends with the same tag seems to be a good enough heuristic:

- False positive rate is zero: If the input is valid, it will be accepted.
- False negative rate is very low: If you terminate a valid HTML at a random point, the chance it ends with a tag is low enough, and verifying it's the same tag helps further.
- False negative rate is sometimes zero: If the outermost element cannot be nested in your specific case (`html`,`body` both apply, even `table`s are rarely nested nowadays), then you will definitely notice an invalid input.

Note that assigning the result as an `innerHTML` and reading it back may produce false positives. The browser is free to rearrange the HTML, even if valid, as it sees fit. Internet Explorer, for example, loves to sort element attributes alphabetically (for some reason). Also, the browser will not complain if you pass it invalid HTML

In regex parlance: `^<(\w+)[^>]*>.*<\/\1>$`

```
if(/^<(\w+)[^>]*>.*<\/\1>$/.test(input)){
  // the input is most likely not truncated
}else{
  // the input is definitely not valid
  // (or it contains multiple top-level elements)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Html Validators.  you specify the DOCTYPE correctly and it'll find anything that is invalid.

1. [HTML Validators W3c](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)
2. [HTML Tidy](http://infohound.net/tidy/)

Comment: Many complete source codes are found to be invalid. This might not be easy to use automatically as a service for completion check.